# The Linux kernels 3.* series won't boot properly upon being customly compiled in Ubuntu 16.04.1 by means of make-kpkg and gcc-4.8.5

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

Recently I upgraded up to **Ubuntu 16.04.1 Xenial** (from **14.04 Trusty**) the build-host where I've compiled different linux kernels so far for my own project. **Ubuntu 16.04.1** implies using a new updated environment for building binaries. These tools include **a new gcc-5.4**, **libc6** (for userspace applications), etc. Also a new Ubuntu supplies (or suggests) a new kernel-package containing a new make-kpkg script and pulling different dependencies like *build-essential*, *binutils*, etc. with it

Ok, my task **is to compile a linux kernel v3.10.12** (**or v3.19**) and run it within a VirtualBox machine (**architecture x86_64, system Ubuntu 16.04.1**). I *used to be able to compile kernel-v3.10.12 and kernel-v3.19 in Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty deployed on the build server with the compiler gcc-4.8 and launch the kernels under the VirtualBox machine I mentioned above*, but now something goes wrong while starting a kernel compiled

For example, let's consider v3.10.12 being compiled and run

For building the kernel **I utilize 'make-kpkg'** script provided by Ubuntu aptitude's package 'kernel-package'. *I build the kernel **for x86_64 using gcc-4.8*** as I have always been doing

Once 'make-kpkg' has compiled the kernel and gathered linux-headers it starts packing them into deb-packages what makes me able to execute 'dpkg -i' on them in the system and install them in a 'debian' way

*Okey, supposing I did it. Then I am going to reboot the system*

*When I choose my compiled kernel in the grub menu, it writes in the screen* "**Loading linux kernel... Loading initial ramdisk**", *then the inscription disappears, **the screen goes black and I see only a cursor in the form of underscore "_" sign** in the top-left side of the screen*. That's all. Nothing is going to happen further. The booting process seems to have stuck

I tried swapping make-kpkg for an old one (from Trusty), swapping compiler gcc-4.8.5 for gcc-4.9, gcc-4.7, even gcc-5.2 having made a couple of supplementations inside the directory include/linux/ for the support of gcc-5.2, but nothing has come off, **the result still persists being the same**

*I tried the same actions* (on the same Ubuntu 16.04.1 and tool-chain) *with new kernels 4.* series* (for example, 4.6) meaning building the kernels, packing them into *.deb packages and installing into the VirtualBox machine and rebooting the system, **and everything goes correctly, I see debug messages in the screen like I have always seen**. I tried to use gcc-4.7, gcc-4.8, gcc-4.9, gcc-5.4 and everything works, I am able to load the linux-kernel-v4.6 appropriately and completely. But when I build 3.10.12 (or 3.19) kernels I cannot boot them properly and cannot have figured out why it has been happening

Actually, what I have found out is that the deal is in the kernel but not in initrd because I managed to substitute the 'broken' kernel by a working one having left 'initrd' built together with the 'broken' kernel and the debug logging started appearing and the kernel was loading until a rootfs came out to be mounted, at that moment the kernel didn't manage to load it and left in initramfs mode

Has someone faced the same issue I am observing? Actually I am almost  exhausted having been struggling with this trouble for days
Maybe someone has any recipes or suggestion how to get rid of the problem?

*I even put the 'panic' function code exactly in the first line of the function "asmlinkage void __init start_kernel(void)" but nothing happened, still the same black screen*

Can the problem be related to a new glibc being used by gcc compiling my kernel? Personally, I am not prone to think so but in the world of linux everything can happen. On the other hand maybe toolchain (ld, as) somehow has affected? I am kindly asking to provide me a help.

I am nearly assured that someone before me has already encountered such an issue, I would have been searching for a topic alike but didn't find anything resembling

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

It's a *glibc* kernel version mismatch, if you need this you could create the *glibc* package such that it supports the kernel version that you need, by using the `--enable-kernel` flag at configuration time.

**Long Answer**

It's highly likely that your *glibc* was compiled in such a way that it only *works* down to a certain version of linux. This is done with the help of the `--enable-kernel` flag at the configuration stage. Any version older than the one specified in `--enable-kernel` will be rejected by *glibc* as a consequence no program will ever be loaded, like the init program presumably *systemd*'s init.

This is from the [configuration help of *glibc*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html)

> `--enable-kernel=version`
>
> This option is currently only 
>   useful on GNU/Linux systems. The version parameter should have the form X.Y.Z and describes the smallest version of the Linux kernel the generated library is expected to support. The higher the version number is, the less compatibility code is added, and the faster the code gets.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer
What glibc's version are you talking about? Glibc used on host-system (where the kernel is compiled) or Glibc on the target-system (where the kernel compiled is run)?

Comment: Actually, as I wrote, I had compiled a kernel on the system Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty with gcc-4.8 and old glibc and the kernel had run properly under the system Ubuntu 16.04 even with a new glibc version on it. It means that the old-versioned kernel was built with old gcc-4.8 using old glibc but it was run on a new system Ubuntu 16.04 where a new glibc was installed . Everything in this case passed in a normal way, I did manage to load the old-versioned kernel appropriately, could accomplish it

Comment: Or you mean that the host-system's glibc somehow affects building process of the old kernel being run on Ubuntu 16.04? Meaning that now I build the old-versioned kernel with a new glibc support and it somehow leads to the issues?

Comment: @dannftk Yes, the system that you try to boot with your custom kernel is causing the issue with *glib* kernel version support.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I succeeded in this problem

Actually what I have done **is to have compiled an old gcc-4.8.5 with an old glibc-2.19 on the host-system where I build the old-versioned kernels**.

**Glibc-2.19 was compiled with an option --enable-kernel=3.10.12 and with headers of an old-versioned linux-3.10.12**. *The compiler has turned out to be like a 'cross-compiler' with usage of glibc-2.19*. So, I built an old kernel with the version 3.10.12 with this 'cross-compiler', which uses glibc-2.19, and **everything has started working in a proper way**

Thanks for the help and directing me to a right way to solve the problem, but I am obliged to notice that the deal was in host-system's glibc used but not in target-system glibc used as I had been assumedly said (but maybe I misunderstood @iharob)